# Is there a way to choose a random constructor to use in python?

Tags: python-2.7, class, constructor

Is there any way to choose a random one of my constructors to use? I have a pretty in depth code, but wrote up a silly one below just to make it as simple as possible.

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scenario, fart, shart):
        self.scenario = scenario
        self.fart = fart
        self.shart = shart   
        self.outcomes = [fart,shart]

    def giveScenario(self):
        print self.scenario

    def chooseOutcome(self):

        outcome = random.choice(self.outcomes)
        print outcome

dinner = Engine('You are at dinner','You fart','You shart')
home = Engine('You are at home','You fart','You shart')
```

Now let's say I was going to make a game where it chooses a random one of these two constructors (either the dinner or home one) to load into this bad boy, is there any way to do that?

Edit: To be clear, I know how to choose a random outcome, i am wondering how I can get this program to run and choose ONLY dinner or ONLY home to run.

```
 [randomly chosen operator].chooseOutcome()
```

Would return either
"You are at dinner" / "You are at home" and the given outcome

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't write the `chooseOutcome` method yourself..?

Comment: @thebjorn Why do you say that?

Comment: I guess @thebjorn asked that, because in `chooseOutcome`'s implementation lies almost the whole answer to your question. If you understand what `chooseOutcome` does and how it does it, you can probably answer your question yourself.

Comment: @das-g Well I feel stupider now, because I did write that part myself. To be clear I asked it correctly, I am asking how to choose a random constructor to be used for when this is ran (either dinner or home), not the random outcome. I know how to randomize the outcome.

Comment: Hint: You want to choose something at random (the first argument to the constructor call, it seems). `chooseOutcome` _does_ choose something (something different, though) at random.

Comment: @das-g I edited my question, i don't think I was being clear on what I actually wanted. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I've completely misunderstood what you're asking, this is pretty easy:

```
dinner = Engine('You are at dinner','You fart','You shart')
home = Engine('You are at home','You fart','You shart')
random.choice([dinner, home]).chooseOutcome()
```

or, if you only need this once and want to avoid unnecessary instantiations:

```
Engine(
    random.choice(['You are at dinner', 'You are at home']),
    'You fart',
    'You shart',
).chooseOutcome()
```

If you need to call several operations on the *same* randomly chosen Engine, just store the result of `random.choice([dinner, home])` or of `Engine(random.choice(['You are at dinner', 'You are at home']), 'You fart','You shart')`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I tried something similar but had dinner and home as a string. I was being stupid and new.

Comment: You're welcome. I figure, now you see why we were pointing you to your existing and working `chooseOutcome` method?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried toying with that for a bit but it did not seem to be working so I just assumed there was a more complex way of accomplishing it, but it was right under my nose.